# In Salat what mispronunciations are acceptable?

Tags: salat, tajweed, pronunciation

In salat (prayer) I like to read it out loud sometimes but I whisper it. When I am supposed to say:

"sub hana rabb ial 'ala"

It comes out like:

"sup hana rapial 'ala"

Even though it's not what I mean. This is how it comes out when I whisper it. Does this change the meaning of the word and invalidate my prayer? Please let me know.

Comment: Well to give a short answer as i'll need a bit time to answer your question well: AFAIK the only think you really should pronounce well is al-Fatiha as it's recitation is fard. Anything else could be acceptable especially if you are not native Arabic speaker!

Answer (score 2):

In Islam acts are based on intention. You didn't intend to do that so your prayer is valid. You wanted to pronounce in rightly but mispronounced it. But your intent was right. The prophet [saw] said:

> Narrated 'Umar bin Al-Khattab (May Allah be pleased with him), reported:
>   Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said, "**The deeds are considered by the intentions,** and a person will get the reward according to his intention. So whoever emigrated for Allah and His Messenger, his emigration will be for Allah and His Messenger; and whoever emigrated for worldly benefits or for a woman to marry, his emigration would be for what he emigrated for".
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

Answer (score 0):

**In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful**

As a general Islamic rule of Salah (prayer), there are some conditions which can invalidate your Salah (prayer). One of them is relevant to the PRONUNCIATION. In other word, it is said that in case that your pronunciation is not true (which changes the meaning), as a consequence it would invalidate your Salah or Namaz.

For instance, as you gave the following example:

> When I am supposed to say:
>
> "sub hana rabb ial 'ala"
>
> it comes out like:
>
> "sup hana rapial 'ala"

It looks wrong, since it has change the correct word to the wrong word of "sup hana rapial 'ala”.  In the meanwhile, to the best of my knowledge, at least at majority of times it can change the meaning.

But, may be mis-pronunciation in Mustahab parts of Salah such as Qunoot doesn't invalidate that.

And Allah knows best

---

**References:**

- [portal.anhar.ir](http://portal.anhar.ir/node/589#gsc.tab=0)
- [farsi.khamenei.ir](http://farsi.khamenei.ir/treatise-content?id=35)
- [sallatt.loxblog.com](http://sallatt.loxblog.com/post/12/%D8%AC%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%84%20%DA%A9%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA%DB%8C%20%DA%A9%D9%87%20%D8%A7%DA%AF%D8%B1%20%D8%AF%D8%B1%20%D9%86%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B2%20%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%87%20%D8%AA%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B8%20%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%AF%20%20%D9%85%D8%B9%D9%86%DB%8C%20%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%87%20%D9%85%DB%8C%20%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%AF.htm)