# Mispronunciation in salat

Tags: salat, mistake

I’ve been suffering with ocd the past few months and I keep repeating salat and I spend 10-30 minutes performing salat because I’m making sure to pronounce everything correctly. My question is does mispronunciation invalidate salat? To be specific if instead of saying once, “subhana rabbi ala wa bi hamdihi” I said “subhana rabbi ala bi hamdihi” does that invalidate my salat? Sometimes in my prayer I will think i said this part wrong but I do not know whether to perform prostration of forgetfulness or if it’s insignificant. Also, if I make a mistake in the surah after Fatiha, does that invalidate salat? Thank you all for your help, I just need help getting through this..

Comment: Thank you for showing me this, did not see that.. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Salat what mispronunciations are acceptable?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28094/in-salat-what-mispronunciations-are-acceptable) and [Can I take a break from prayer until I fix the mistakes?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38593/11938)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alhamdulillah, mispronunciation does not invalidate salah;as long as u do not leave out any of the essential elements like the recitation of Surah Fateha, or going for Ruku and Sejdah etc. However, it decreases beauty of your salah. When you are aware of  mistakes or the problem of forgetfulness arises; it is recommended that you perform Sahu-Sejdah before ending the Salah. 
As we are not from Arabic speaking countries, it is obvious that some problems relating to pronunciation may arise. Off course it would be better if u can fix yourself and I suggest that you practice recitation out side your Salah and consult an Arabic teacher who can easily teach the rules relating to pronunciation. After significant efforts if there are yet mistakes, Insha-Allah, our Lord, the Forgiver and the Merciful will forgive us.
If any part of my explanation is incorrect and if somebody knows better, please do correct me. According to my understanding of Islam, I have answered.May Allah (SWT) accept my effort.

Comment: Thank you brother, appreciate the help. Sorry one more thing. So if I had a minor mispronounciation in ruku it would be fine as well?